# Implementing 3 way partitioning for quick sort

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, dutch-national-flag-problem

I am trying to implement 3-Way partitioning for quick sort. 
I tested with a lot of custom test cases but if works fine, but it fails for some unknown cases. I am unable to figure out where am I going.

Here's the code.
Partitioning:

```
int* partition3(vector<long long int> &a, int l, int r) {
  int* m = new int[2];

  long long int x = a[l];

  int j = l;
  int k = l;

  for (int i = l + 1; i <= r; i++) {

    if (a[i] < x) {
      j++;
      k++;
      swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
    else if(a[i]==x)
    { 
      k++;
      swap(a[i],a[k]);
    }
  }
  swap(a[l], a[j]);    
  m[0]=j;
  m[1]=k;
  return m;
}
```

Sort Function:

```
void randomized_quick_sort(vector<long long int> &a, int l, int r) {
  if (l >= r) {
    return;
  }

  int k = l + rand() % (r - l + 1);

  swap(a[l], a[k]);

  int* m = new int[2];

  m = partition3(a, l, r);

  randomized_quick_sort(a, l, m[0]-1);
  randomized_quick_sort(a, m[1], r);
}
```

I will be grateful if you help me out.

Comment: Unrelated: you leak memory. Instead of returning `int*`, return `std::pair<int, int>`. Related: which loop invariants in `partition3` do you have? How would you prove that this function works correctly?

Comment: You can't have both the `smaller than pivot` and `equal to pivot` go the left in the array - they'll get mixed up. Also, don't the equal ones need to be moved to the middle after partitioning?

Comment: @evg I hypothesized that `j` will point to the last element of the `smaller than pivot` part and `k` to the starting of `larger than pivot` part. In between those non unique element will be present. This was done incrementing `j` and `k` when we encounter smaller than pivot and incrementing `k` alone when we encounter equal to element.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried swapping operation on `a[i] and a[k]`. It shifts the equals to middle, But I dont know how that happens, I observed it working while I was developing the algorithm. so, I used it here :)

Comment: You should step through the code with small input samples, like `2213`, and verify that it works as you expected, fix it if it doesn't. You can do the debugging on paper if you don't know how to use a software debugger.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I dubbed on paper, it works perfectly fine. But when I submit this solution it fails a test case(unknown one). I tried stress testing but i am unable to generate large input samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to implement three-way partition that is provably correct is to use the method of loop invariants. For simplicity and genericity let's work with iterators. Consider the following invariants:

```
In the range
  [first, i)  all elements are less than pivot
  [i, j)      all elements are equal to pivot
  [j, k)      unpartitioned range
  [k, last)   all elements are greater than pivot
```

Initially, `i = first`, `j = first`, and `k = last`, so that the whole range `[first, last)` is unpartitioned. At each iteration we'll contract this range by one element. Finally, `j = k`, so that the whole range is three-way partitioned.

The following code implements this idea:

```
template<class It>
std::pair<It, It> three_way_partition(It first, It last) {
    assert(first != last);    
    const auto& pivot = *--last;

    auto i = first, j = first, k = last;
    while (j != k)
        if (*j < pivot)
            std::iter_swap(i++, j++);
        else if (pivot < *j)
            std::iter_swap(j, --k);
        else
            ++j;

    std::iter_swap(j++, last);
    return {i, j};
}
```

Here I used the last element as the pivot. This choice simplifies the code, but is not essential.

Quick sort algorithm that uses this function is:

```
template<class It, class Gen>
void randomized_quick_sort(It first, It last, Gen&& gen) {
    if (last - first <= 1)
        return;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<typename It::difference_type> 
        dist(0, last - first - 1);
    std::iter_swap(first + dist(gen), last - 1);

    const auto p = three_way_partition(first, last);
    randomized_quick_sort(first, p.first, gen);
    randomized_quick_sort(p.second, last, gen);
}
```

Sample use case:

```
std::mt19937 gen; // you might want to initialize it with std::random_device
std::vector<int> vec;
// initialize vec

randomized_quick_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r7HrUb)